# Cannot deserialize array of integers with WebAPI?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I'm sending the following :

```
{
    "setIds": ["1", "2"],
    "folderIds": ["3", "4"],
    "filter": "FILTERED"
};
```

To an API endpoint that accepts a SessionDto:

```
[DataContract]
public class SessionDto
{

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public Array FolderIds { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public Array SetIds { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Filter { get; set; }

}
```

SetIds and FolderIds are always null though; Filter comes through just fine.  I'm using newtonsoft.json.serialization.  Any idea why this wouldn't be working, or how I can further debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public int[] FolderIds { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public int[] SetIds { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Filter { get; set; }
```

Try int arrays